# CSS 'fake' frames not working in FF, Chrome & Safari but fine in IE

Tags: css, google-chrome, positioning, frames, absolute

I am kinda new to css and a lot of what I am doing is copied or googled so I am totally chill with the prospect of it being horribly wrong. Let me tell you what I am trying to do:

I have a php forum script (my little forum) which I want to slot in to a standard css fake-frames type wrapper with a header, footer and content. Now the forum software uses smarty template engine so I am editing the tpl file itself. I know this all works fine because I have had no problems getting wrappers I generated in dreamweaver to work. Its the hand done one which is giving me trouble.

Now I can just use dreamweaver to make my css frameset but its lazy and I want to know *why* its not working in Firefox, Chrome and Safari. I'm certain its just syntax.

Firstly you can visit my site in IE9 and see it working as designed: url removed because of traffic - thanks!

I have the forum script nestled in a 990px wrapper using seperate header, content and footer wrappers positioned within the main smarty theme template for the forum's index page. Looks good. No worries.

Now if you try the same site in Chrome, Firefox or Safari you see that the header and footer are present and working as intended but the 'content' is just loading up at 100% page width and ignoring the css stylsheet settings for absolute positioning.

Here's my css:

```css
/***************STRUCTURE***************************/

* { margin: 0; padding: 0px; }

/* Absolute positioned header for all browsers*/
#header-wrapper {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:6em;
}

/* Resets the header position to fixed for real browsers such as Firefox*/
body>div#header-wrapper {
    position:fixed;
}

#headercustom {
    height:6em;
    width:990px;
    margin:0 auto;
}

#content-wrapper {
    padding:6em 0 0 0;
    margin-left:0;
    margin-top:0;
    voice-family: "\"}\""; 
    voice-family:inherit;
    margin-left:16px;
    padding-bottom:60px;
}

body>#content-wrapper {
    margin-left:0;
}

#contentcustom {
    width:990px;
    margin:0 auto;
}

#footer-wrapper {
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    height:60px;
}

body>#footer-wrapper {
    position:fixed;
}

#footercustom {
    width:990px;
    height:60px;
    margin:0 auto;
}

/***************STYLE***************************/

#headercustom,
#footercustom {
    background:#fff;
    color:#000;
}
```

Here's the markup:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="content-wrapper">
            <div id="contentcustom">
            content ie forum main script in here
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="header-wrapper">
            <div id="headercustom">
            Header content here
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="footer-wrapper">
            <div id="footercustom">
            Footer content here
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

NB: the markup is chopped up and placed in the smarty template appropriately its shown here purely for reference. It must be working fine since it looks good in IE so I am pretty sure its a css syntax issue I have. Being new and ignorant of the differences between how the browsers iterpret such things.

Any help you could give me to understand why my positioning is being ignored in Chrome, FF and Safari but not in IE would be ace. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@ the link you mentioned on your site, if you view the HTML source of the page, you will see that **your page has got a conditional comment which breaks your HTML on FF, Chrome etc and your page works only in IE**. You have got a code like:

This above line of HTML code means that this would be read as:
 on Internet Explorer
Blank (nothing) on all other browsers

Codes like these are called conditional comments which run only on IE and should be used only when they are must to write some IE specific code. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_comment

Since you are new to developing UI, I would suggest you to:

- Save the Page as HTML
- Indent it with proper tabbing and spacing
- Use tools like Firebug on Firefox (it would save you a lot of time with previewing HTML and CSS edits you wish to make)
- Make this page work fine on all browsers
- Now implement the changes you did to achieve this with your template engine.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I removed the condition for IE from that div and it now works as intended in all browsers. When I checked the css file for the forum template there was an additional section for this div which arranges the threads and sets an over-riding width etc. I must have missed it! Thanks again for explaining and I will now look out for conditional tags in the future!